# Android Palette working only on some of RecyclerView items

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to generate a color Palette for each CardView I have inside a RecyclerView, and to color the card based on the Palette generated.
However, for some weird reason, only the last two CardViews of the RecyclerView get colored.

This is my code (it's in C#, using Xamarin, but it's almost identical to the Java code):

RecyclerAdapter:

```
    public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, Palette.IPaletteAsyncListener
    {
        private List<Book> mBooks;
        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        private Context mContext;
        private int mCurrentPosition = -1;
        private bool isPaletteGenerated = false;
        MyView myHolder;
        public RecyclerAdapter(List<Book> books, RecyclerView recyclerView, Context context)
        {
            mBooks = books;
            mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
            mContext = context;
        }

        public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public View mMainView { get; set; }
            public TextView mTitle { get; set; }
            public ImageView mCoverImage { get; set; }
            public int mCoverImageResourceID { get; set; }
            public CardView mCard { get; set; }

            public MyView(View view) : base(view)
            {
                mMainView = view;
            }
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {

            View bookItem = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.item_book, parent, false);


            TextView bookTitle = bookItem.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.bookTitle);
            ImageView coverImage = bookItem.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.coverImage);
            CardView card = bookItem.FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.card);

            MyView view = new MyView(bookItem) { mTitle = bookTitle, mCoverImage = coverImage, mCard = card};
            return view;
        }

        public override async void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            myHolder = holder as MyView;
            myHolder.mMainView.Click += mMainView_Click;
            myHolder.mTitle.Text = mBooks[position].Title;
            myHolder.mCoverImage.SetImageDrawable(mBooks[position].Cover.Drawable);
            myHolder.mCoverImageResourceID = mBooks[position].imageResourceId;

            if (position > mCurrentPosition)
            {
                int currentAnim = Resource.Animation.slide_left_to_right;
                //SetAnimation(myHolder.mMainView, currentAnim);
                mCurrentPosition = position;
            }

            Bitmap photo = await BitmapFactory.DecodeResourceAsync(mContext.Resources, myHolder.mCoverImageResourceID);
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable)mBooks[position].Cover.Drawable);
            Bitmap image = bitmapDrawable.Bitmap;

            var palette = Palette.From(photo).MaximumColorCount(16).Generate(this);


        }   

        public void OnGenerated(Palette palette)
        {

            if (palette == null)
                return;
            try
            {
                if (palette.LightVibrantSwatch != null)
                {
                    var lightVibrant = new Color(palette.LightVibrantSwatch.Rgb);
                    myHolder.mCard.SetCardBackgroundColor(lightVibrant);
                }
                if (palette.DarkVibrantSwatch != null)
                {
                    var darkVibrant = new Color(palette.DarkVibrantSwatch.Rgb);
                    myHolder.mCard.SetCardBackgroundColor(darkVibrant);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return mBooks.Count; }
        }
    }
```

Fragment in which the RecyclerView is inside:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        mRecyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.booksRecyclerView);
        mBooks = new List<Book>();
        ImageView cover = new ImageView(Activity);

        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Torat_Hamachane1);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "תורת המחנה א' - הלכות יום ויום", Cover = cover, imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.Torat_Hamachane1}); 


        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Activity, 2);
        mRecyclerView.SetForegroundGravity(GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        SimpleItemAnimator x = null;

        mRecyclerView.SetItemAnimator(x);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mBooks, mRecyclerView, Activity);
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);


        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.kitzurTHM);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "קיצור תורת המחנה - הלכות יום ויום ושבת", Cover = cover, imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.kitzurTHM });

        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.halkasPurim);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "הלכה כסדרה - הלכות פורים", Cover = cover, imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.halkasPurim });

        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.halkasPesach);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "הלכה כסדרה - הלכות פסח", Cover = cover, imageResourceId= Resource.Drawable.halkasPesach });

        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.netzach);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "שו\"ת נצח יהודה", Cover = cover , imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.netzach});

        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.tankim);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "טיפול בטנקים בשבת", Cover = cover , imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.tankim});

        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.tipulBeChalalim);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "טיפול בחללים בשבת", Cover = cover , imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.tipulBeChalalim});

        return view;

    }
```

Can someone can please help me find out why only the last two items get colored?

Thanks!

**Update:**
Started bounty. Desperate for help.

Comment: Available here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r29x7gryixtj5gw/AACyA6aEoorodSAatJhZcOQGa?dl=0

Comment: Please also include instructions to replicate the current behavior with your sample project.

Comment: In the meantime, did you look at this sample? https://github.com/saulmm/OpenLibra-Material/blob/285fcca8fe50a0deb6f3034c5f4918537a4edb5c/app/src/main/java/com/saulmm/openlibra/views/adapters/BookAdapter.java#L105

Comment: To replicate the behavior: Choose the second item in the navigation drawer, and the recyclerview will show. There you will see colored rectangles, but only the last two are a palette from there image.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the sample.

Comment: Despite the problems you are having. Whats your goal? You have that recycler with imagens and a label with a blue transparent background in the bottom. Do you only want to change the color of the card to a color from palete?

Comment: I got a lot of exceptions related with outofmemry. Need to comment trycatch bitmap decodes.

Comment: I want to color either the card or the transparent rectangle with the palette.

Comment: What do you mean by bitmap decodes?

Comment: BitmapFactory.DecodeResourceAsync Throws out of memory. Nexus 5.

Comment: Why? And what should I do about it?

Comment: Also, by the way, if you have any other comments on the code, feel free to say. I have some other problems too...

Comment: First im focused on the Pallete. Later we see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed up some things, here is the full adapter, i dind't optimized any of the code, but it works.

In summary solved it like this:

```
var palette = Palette.From(((BitmapDrawable)myHolder.mCoverImage.Drawable).Bitmap).MaximumColorCount(16).Generate(new PalleteGeneration(myHolder));
```

Here is the PaleteGeneration:

```
public class PalleteGeneration : Java.Lang.Object, Palette.IPaletteAsyncListener
{
    private MyView _holder;

    public PalleteGeneration(MyView holder) 

        _holder = holder;
    }

    public void OnGenerated(Palette palette)
    {
        if (palette == null)
            return;

        if (palette.LightVibrantSwatch != null)
        {
            var lightVibrant = new Color(palette.LightVibrantSwatch.Rgb);
            _holder.mCard.SetCardBackgroundColor(lightVibrant);

        }
        else if (palette.LightMutedSwatch != null)
        {
            var lightVibrant = new Color(palette.LightMutedSwatch.Rgb);
            _holder.mCard.SetCardBackgroundColor(lightVibrant);

        }
        if (palette.DarkVibrantSwatch != null)
        {
            var darkVibrant = new Color(palette.DarkVibrantSwatch.Rgb);
            _holder.TitleBackground.SetBackgroundColor(darkVibrant);
        }
        else if (palette.DarkMutedSwatch != null)
        {
            var darkVibrant = new Color(palette.DarkMutedSwatch.Rgb);
            _holder.TitleBackground.SetBackgroundColor(darkVibrant);
        }               
}
```

Get the full RecyclerAdapter [here](https://gist.github.com/jzeferino/70ed3dfd96dfd14e3584092debc3af78).

Final result:

[image]

Comment: you onBindViewHolder is wrongly implemented. you have myHolder = holder as MyView; which means myHolder gets updated each time onBindViewholder gets called, so by the time palette operation is completed all the onbindViewHolder gets called and would have instance of last item of the list. you have gotaway with it using Palette.From(((BitmapDrawable)myHolder.mCoverImage.Drawable).Bitmap because here you are passing each instance.

Comment: As i told in my post, I didn't optimized any previous code. I just fixed the issue with Pallete. The Adapter you see is the user original just with my Pallete fix. But appreciate your comment.

Comment: actually you should refractor your code, thats why I added comment.
myHolder = holder as MyView is not a good practice , you should use your viewholder reference. And you have did that by using 
var palette = Palette.From(((BitmapDrawable)myHolder.mCoverImage.Drawable).Bitmap).MaximumColorCount(16).Generate(new PalleteGeneration(myHolder));

Comment: you shouldn't use MyView myHolder; and update its instance in onBindVieHolder, myHolder = holder as MyView; This is not a reliable implementation

Comment: I did that change see the gist. But to be clear, the field myHolder was only used inside the onbindviewHolder so it has no problem. It should't be a field, yes i know but it was the original code and my main focus was on make pallete work, as the user needed. I just changed it to a variable only scoped inside onBindViewHolder. Its ok now. Please lets clean the comments and maitain only the important ones.